# PHP Logic - Don't know where else to ask

Tags: php, logic

I'm sure this isn't the right place to ask this..

Is there a better way to write this so it increments by itself indefinitely?

```
if ($page == '1') $pagv = $x;
    if ($page == '2') $pagv = $x + 4; 
    if ($page == '3') $pagv = $x + 8;
    if ($page == '4') $pagv = $x + 12;
    if ($page == '5') $pagv = $x + 16;   
    if ($page == '6') $pagv = $x + 20;
```

And is there a proper place to ask such questions?

Comment: switch case will be more better....

Comment: Nevermind! $x = ($page * 4 ) - 4;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do simply -

```
$pagv = $x + (($page -1) * 4); // if the factor is always 4
```

Or if the `factor` is not fixed then use a `variable` for it and use it accordingly.

```
$factor = 4;
$pagv = $x + (($page -1) * $factor);
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. 60 hours a week staring at this screen.. Brain is fried.

Answer (score 0):

try `switch` case

```
switch ($page) {
    case "1":
        $x;
        break;
    case "2":
        $pagv = $x + 4;
        break;
    case "3":
        $pagv = $x + 8;
        break;
    case "4":
        $pagv = $x + 12;
        break;
    case "5":
        $pagv = $x + 16;
        break;
    case "6":
        $pagv = $x + 20;
        break;
    default:
        echo "plz enter page no";
}
```

Comment: This would work but you would still have to enter each case individually, which may not be feasible if the underlying data is user generated, for example, and you don't know how many pages you'll need when the code is being written.